# Detecting a finger being held on an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am trying to have an image that when the user touches it, it wiggles and as soon as the user lifts their finger it stops.

Is there a gesture that I can use to detect when the finger is down, not just on the initial touch, or when the user moves there finger?

I have tried a LongPress gesture, but that does not get called the entire time the finger is on the view.  Can anyone help me with the best way to active this.  Right now i am doing it using touchesBegin, touchesMoved, touchesEnd, but i was wondering if there is a better way.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
Based on the comments, I slightly misunderstood the original question, so I edit my answer to a different solution, which hopefully is a bit more clear (and answers the actual question - not the one that was in my head).

A LongPress gesture is continuous (where a tap gesture is not).  That means, the recognizer callback will continue to be invoked until the gesture is complete - which does not happen until the "longpress" is released.  So, the following should do what you want.  NOTE: I think you want to "start shaking" a view when the long-press is recognized, then "stop shaking" the view when the fingers are released.  I just pretended you have functions for that.  Substitute appropriately.

```
 - (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        StartShakingView(gestureRecognizer.view);
    } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        StopShakingView(gestureRecognizer.view);
    }
}
```

Comment: but which UIGestureRecognizer do you use?

Comment: What do you mean 'finish shaking when the gesture fires'?

Comment: @jody: Yeah, that's smooth. Assuming you want springboard-esque behavior, as opposed to starting the wiggle immediately. Maybe you can set the minimum duration very low?

Comment: You can always set the initial delay to 0 for the long press to be recognized, then it happens "pretty fast."

Answer (score 1):

The Apple [Touches sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435) includes code that demonstrate using both UIResponder and UIGestureRecognizer methods.

Either should work for what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but first, can I use touchesBegin, etc, with the UIGestures? I am thinking, I can only use one or the other... is that true?  Second, I want my animation to happen the whole time the finger is down, there will most likely be no movement so how do I do act upon the finger being down?

Comment: I've not tried mixing UIGestureRecognizer with UIResponder, but I don't know any reason that you couldn't use a mixture of both. It sounds like you're trying to trigger your animation based on some continuing stream of events while a touch is being held? If that's your question, then I'd suggest that you do your animation on a separate thread and send it messages to start and stop animation. Your animation would be similar to the way UIActivityIndicator is used. I don't have an example of that, but searching for "background animation" or similar should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Apparently both will not work together by default, see here http://mobworld.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/touches-cancelled-gesture/  That is my problem, if I can get them to work together I am good to go.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't know that. Have you tried setting `UIGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = FALSE;`? It sounds like that might be the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - you could make the image a UIButton, and start the wiggle on TouchDown, and stop it on TouchUpInside or TouchUpOutside

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to *subclass* UIGestureRecognizer, which, as I recall, gets the `touchesBegan:...` and associated methods. Read the notes on subclassing in the UIGestureRecognizer reference. Or use a UIButton as SomaMan suggests.